# How to find certain probabilities in transition matrices

Tags: probability, transition-matrix

A unit consists of three circuit elements in parallel; it will be in working order as long as at least one of the elements is working. The unit is examined every hour and if it is not in working order it will be replaced with a new identical unit, in which all three elements are working. The time it takes to replace a unit is measured in a whole number of hours, and it is a random variable T with probabilities:
$P(T = k) = q·(1 – q)^{k – 1}$ for k = 1, 2, ... .

The lifetimes of the elements, **L1**, **L2**, and **L3** – which also are measured in a whole numbers of hours – are independent random variables, identically distributed with probabilities:
$P(L_j = k) = p·(1 – p)^k$ for k = 0, 1, 2, . . . and j = 1, 2, 3.

Let Xn be the number of elements that are working after n hours, supposing $X_0 = 3$. This will then be a time homogeneous Markov chain.

Determine the one-step transition probability matrix for this process.

Can someone please explain how to find for example $P_{21}$, if P is the transition matrix of $X_n$, and i = 2 and j = 1? The answer is $P_{21} = 2p(1-p)$, but I have no idea why